# How to include .swift file from other .swift file in an immediate mode?

Tags: swift, immediate-mode

Having a file with function definition `bar.swift`:

```
func bar() {
    println("bar")
}
```

And a script to be run in immediate mode `foo.swift`:

```
#!/usr/bin/xcrun swift -i
bar()
```

How do you import `bar.swift`'s `bar()` function from `foo.swift`?

Comment: First off you should be using `#!/usr/bin/swift` instead of xcrun.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: I *think* that depends on the OS. On OS X 10.9 you have to use xcrun. On 10.10 you can call swift/swiftc directly.

Answer (score 31):

I think the answer right now is that you can't split code across multiple files unless you compile the code. Executing with `#!/usr/bin/swift` is only possible for single file scripts.

It's obviously a good idea to  file an enhancement request at http://bugreport.apple.com/, but in the mean time you're going to have to compile the code before executing it.

Also, your `foo.swift` file cannot have that name, you have to rename it to `main.swift`. If there are multiple files being complied, then only `main.swift` is allowed to have code at the top level.

So, you have these two files:

main.swift:

```
bar()
```

bar.swift:

```
func bar() {
    println("bar")
}
```

And compile/execute the code with:

```
$ swiftc main.swift bar.swift -o foobar

$ ./foobar 
bar
```

If all your swift files are in the same directory, you could shorten the compile command:

```
$ swiftc *.swift -o foobar
```

Or if you want to search child directories:

```
$ find . -iname '*.swift' | xargs swiftc -o foobar
```

Comment: Thanks, works for me. For some reason I don't have `swiftc` installed, but all the above also applies to `xcrun swiftc`.

Comment: @Thilo Make sure you have the latest version of Xcode from the App Store and, then after that run `xcode-select --install` in terminal. You should have `swiftc` after that. When I tried to use the code you're using I got a compile error saying that syntax is no-longer allowed. So you're clearly running an old version.

Answer (score 0):

Write a bash script to concatenate the files. The script below pre-pends the library file to the front of your script before execution:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat $HOME/my_swift/my_library_to_add.swift $1.swift > t.swift
swift t.swift
```

As the resulted file is the single use, you can place it on the RAM drive. Here is the more advanced version that creates or reuses the tiny 1 Mb RAM drive as required.

```
if [ ! -d /Volumes/swift_buffer ]; then
   diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'swift_buffer' `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://2048`
fi

cat $HOME/my_swift/my_library_to_add.swift $1.swift > /Volumes/swift_buffer/t.swift   
swift /Volumes/swift_buffer/t.swift
```

This creates a tiny RAM drive with the capacity of 1 Mb only, big enough for any utility script and simple library.

The mounted RAM drive will be visible in the Finder, from where it can be ejected. I do not dispose it directly in the script as allocating takes time.