# How to develop in Swift without Xcode IDE

Tags: xcode, macos, shell, swift, scripting

I want to put together a runnable script and a class to include from a separate module.

If I put the class into the script like this, it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env swift
class HelloWorld {
    func greet() {
        print("Hello World")
    }
}
var h = HelloWorld()
h.greet()
```

However, when I put the HelloWorld class into a HelloWorld.swift module, I have found no solution to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do:

```
$ swift HelloWorld.swift
```

And you `HelloWorld.swift`:

```swift
class HelloWorld {
    func greet() {
        print("Hello World")
    }
}
var h = HelloWorld()
h.greet()
```

**Important**: as of Swift 1.2 you can only have **one** big scripting file. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27437969/225503)