# Does Swift 2.0 allow a Swift script to use multiple files?

Tags: ios, macos, swift, scripting

When making a swift script I'd like to breakdown my code into separate files and import files at my whim. However, previous Stackoverflow posts state it's impossible in Swift 1.2

[How to include .swift file from other .swift file in an immediate mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342940/how-to-include-swift-file-from-other-swift-file-in-an-immediate-mode/27437969#27437969),

or provide workarounds involving file concatenation

[Is there a way to have a Swift script use multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069043/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-swift-script-use-multiple-files)

My question is the following: Does Swift 2.0 address and resolve the issue of importing one Swift file from another Swift file?

Comment: What is a Swift script, the word script is throwing me.

Comment: Zaph, a Swift script is a swift file that can be executed outside of an Xcode project. Please check on the first link for an example.